# Prerequisites for Windows Phone 8.0/8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently planning to code a cordova app for iOS, Android and Windows Phone. I just don't get it in detail with the cordova documentation what it takes to package a Windows Phone 8/8.1 app.

I understood, that I need Windows 8 Pro (64 Bit) in order to use the device emulator. But does it have to be a Windows 8.0 in order to create Phone 8.0 apps or can I also create such apps with Windows 8.1 Pro? And what about Visual Studio? Is an express edition enough or do I need an edition I need to pay for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight apps) with Windows 8.1 and VS 2013 Express or higher. 
For universal Windows Phone apps , you have  to select Windows Phone in the target devices.

If you haven't already , you can also use VS 2015 Preview to develop for WP 8 or 8.1 on Windows 8.1 Pro 
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs

To develop apps for all platforms (Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1):
•Windows 8.1, 32 or 64-bit Home, Pro, or Enterprise editions, along with Visual Studio 2013 Express* or higher.